# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\arctan{e^{a+x}} - \arctan{e^{b+x}}) dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\arctan({e^{a+x}}) - \arctan({e^{b+x}})) dx $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=b$, the integral vanishes. Differentiating it with respect to $a$ gives$$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{e^{a+x}dx}{1+e^{2a+2x}}=\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{e^{y}dy}{1+e^{2y}}=2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-y}dy}{1+e^{-2y}}=2\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\cdots\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$So the original integral is $\frac{\pi}{2}(a-b)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Differentiate with respect to a parameter.